# How can we translate product attribute in Saleor dashboard?

Tags: saleor

I checked the translation page on saleor dashboard, but there I can only edit the product attribute name only.

I want to translate the product attributes value.

For example, products has an attribute **features**. This attribute will have different value for each product. So, I want to translate the value of this attribute not just the attribute name.

Is there a way to do this from dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Saleor already added solution to my question. Take pull in master branch and you will see option to translate Attributes in product translation page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Saleor 3 you can find it in the translation tab/attributes

[image]

Comment: As I already explained, I want to translate an text type attribute not an drop-down type.
Text type doesn't have values like shown in screenshot.

Comment: Size is the attribute name/type, and Values are options in the dropdown. Both are translatable, not sure what else is missing, you would have to be more specific, perhaps screenshot would help

Comment: Buddy that's what I am saying that, size attribute has some values which can be selected from a drop-down. Means we can translate those values and size field will only have a value from one of them.
But now assume a text attribute, which can have any value and not selected from some drop-down type values. This attribute will appear as a text field on UI and user can enter any paragraph and save it.

Comment: Oh wow, I see now, I was not aware of the new attributes features, they were used to be only dropdown type

Comment: They just added this feature recently.